# How do I swap two random values from a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to swap two random values from a dicitonary

```
def alphabetcreator():
        letters = random.sample(range(97,123), 26)
        newalpha = []
        engalpha =['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
        alphasmerged = {}
        for i in letters:
            newalpha.append(chr(i))
        alphasmerged = dict(zip(engalpha, newalpha))
        return(alphabetsmerged)
```

This code gives me my two different alphabets, putting them into a dictionary so I can translate between one and the other. I now need to randomly swap two of the values whilst keeping all the rest the same. How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "swap"? reverse key-value, or positioning in original list?

Comment: 1) You don't need parentheses on the return statement 2) What is your expected output?

Comment: @Ajax1234 I mean positioning in original list. For example, my first dictionary may be {'a': 'h', 'b': 'd', 'c': 'y'} and then I want it so that it will randomly pick to swap these round making {'a': 'd', 'b': h, 'c': 'y'} as an example

Comment: @darthbith 1) Thanks, I've only recently started teaching myself python 2) The output for that gives me a dictionary like {a': 'h', 'b': 'd', 'c': 'y'} and I then want to randomly swap two of these values to end up with something like {'a': 'd', 'b': h, 'c': 'y'} as an example

Comment: @Sh1elds please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You can first use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html#random.sample) to randomly pick two different values from a collection.
From the doc:

> Return a k length list of unique elements chosen from the population sequence or set. Used for random sampling without replacement.

Use this function on the keys of your dictionary to have two distinct keys.
In Python 3, you can directly use it on a `dict_keys` object.
In Python 2, you can either convert `d.keys()` into a `list`, or directly pass the dictionary to the `sample`.

```
>>> import random
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> k1, k2 = random.sample(d.keys(), 2)          # Python 3
>>> k1, k2 = random.sample(d, 2)                 # Python 2
>>> k1, k2
['a', 'b']
```

Then, you can in-place-ly swap two values of a collection.

```
>>> d[k1], d[k2] = d[k2], d[k1]
>>> d
{'b': 1, 'a': 2}
```

Comment: @JoeIddon My mistake, I made a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import random
engalpha =['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
new_dict = {a:b for a, b in zip(engalpha, map(chr, random.sample(range(97,123), 26)))}
key_val = random.choice(list(new_dict.keys()))
final_dict = {b if a == key_val else a:a if a == key_val else b for a, b in new_dict.items()}
```

Regarding your recent comment:

```
import random
s = {'a': 'h', 'b': 'd', 'c': 'y'} 
random_dict = [(a, b) for a, b in random.sample(list(s.items()), 2)]
new_dict = {a:b for a, b in zip([i[0] for i in sorted(random_dict, key=lambda x:x[0])], [i[-1] for i in sorted(random_dict, key=lambda x:x[-1])][::-1])}
final_dict = {a:new_dict.get(a, b) for a, b in s.items()}
```

Output (randomly generated):

```
{'a': 'y', 'c': 'h', 'b': 'd'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {12: 34, 67: 89}
k, v = random.choice(list(d.items()))
d[v] = k
d.pop(k)
```

which when running, gave the random output of `d` as:

```
{12: 34, 89: 67}
```

Comment: This swaps a key with its value, which is not what the OP wanted.  The OP wanted to swap two values.